# Strapi plugins not loading in prod environment

Tags: node.js, strapi

I’m trying to deploy a project to a german shared hoster called uberspace. I do however face severe problems getting plugins to work. Locally when building with prod and then starting the prod server (just like I would eventually do on my server) everything works fine. When I try logging into the admin panel on my server I’m getting an error for ckeditor-plugin

```
GET https://reeed2.uber.space/ckeditor5/ckeditor-config net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I’m getting the same for the menu-plugin. Basically I’m getting this exception for all manually installed plugins. Removing the plugins will get me to the admin panel again.

I can’t get my head around this and I’m totally lost. I also don’t seem to have any logs anywhere to get more detailed information on these errors.

Is there maybe something specific to plugins that I need to consider when deploying the app? I basically just built it via `NODE_ENV=production npm run strapi build` which should in theory use my config located in `confi/env/production/server.js` which contains the following:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  proxy: true,
  url: env('URL', 'https://reeed2.uber.space'),
  port: env('PORT', '1337'), // This custom port will be important to point a domain to the service
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  app: {
    keys: env.array('APP_KEYS')
  },
})
```

The environment variables are readable to the config file, when I console.log them they get displayed in stdout.
Nevertheless, I can’t login to the admin and my frontend can’t get any content that is delivered from plugins. Is there maybe some crucial build step I’m missing when building and deploying to a productive environment?

If I build for prod and run prod locally with npm run start, everything works, strangely. Doing the same on the server doesn’t work. Unfortunately the logs from the strapi-server don’t throw any exception or anything other than HTTP200s.

Any help would be appreciated, greetz
derelektrischemoench

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using this plugin https://market.strapi.io/plugins/@ckeditor-strapi-plugin-ckeditor

In your Strapi project you need to create the following folder with the following file and code.

Here is an example from my project where I am using an email plugin in production.

[image]

So in your project you will need to create the following inside the `config` folder.

`env/production/plugins.js`

And inside the `plugins.js` file you would add the following.

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  ckeditor: {
    enabled: true,
    resolve: "./src/plugins/strapi-plugin-ckeditor"
  },
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Paul, thx for the input so far, I've tried this, but it didn't work for me, it threw an exception that the plugin couldn't be found. After having consulted the docs again I came up with this

 ckeditor: {
    enabled: true
  },:

This however didn't work either. I've also noticed something curious when looking at the requests when logging on dev vs on my server: it tries to GET https://reeed2.uber.space/menus/config which 404s. curiously it tries port 443 for this, vs on localhost it tries port 1337, which would be correct. Is there some config I'm missing here to force port 1337 ?